# How to programmatically insert schema code to wordpress so that it automatically works for target post type

Tags: wordpress, schema.org, json-ld

I have this schema json code which I need to add to WordPress. I know how to add this to individual post but I am looking for a situation where I don't need to this manually per post. I want to insert the code so that it works automatically for the specific post type which I am targeting which is in this case Matches. I am not sure how to go about this. I have custom fields which I was thinking of inserting within this code using php but I am not sure it's possible that way. Please help, thanks.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context":"http://schema.org",
    "@type":"SportsEvent",
    "name": "Team A vs Team B",
    "description": "Team A vs Team B for League Match",
    "startDate": "2020-03-01",
    "endDate": "2020-03-01",
    "competitor": [
    {
        "@type": "SportsTeam",
        "name": "Team A",
        "image":"https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/650.png"
        },
    {
        "@type": "SportsTeam",
        "name": "Team B",
        "image":"https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/680.png"
    }
    ],
    "location": {
        "@type": "Place",
        "address": "Stadium of Team A"
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this function to your theme's `functions.php` file

```
function sports_event_schema() {
echo '
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context":"http://schema.org",
    "@type":"SportsEvent",
    "name": "Team A vs Team B",
    "description": "Team A vs Team B for League Match",
    "startDate": "2020-03-01",
    "endDate": "2020-03-01",
    "competitor": [
    {
        "@type": "SportsTeam",
        "name": "Team A",
        "image":"https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/650.png"
        },
    {
        "@type": "SportsTeam",
        "name": "Team B",
        "image":"https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/680.png"
    }
    ],
    "location": {
        "@type": "Place",
        "address": "Stadium of Team A"
    }
}
</script>';
}
if ( 'Matches' == get_post_type() ) {
 add_action('wp_footer', 'sports_event_schema');
}
```

Another option is to add the json straight in your header or footer and add the if statement only:

```
<?php if ( 'Matches' == get_post_type() ) : ?>
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context":"http://schema.org",
    "@type":"SportsEvent",
    "name": "Team A vs Team B",
    "description": "Team A vs Team B for League Match",
    "startDate": "2020-03-01",
    "endDate": "2020-03-01",
    "competitor": [
    {
        "@type": "SportsTeam",
        "name": "Team A",
        "image":"https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/650.png"
        },
    {
        "@type": "SportsTeam",
        "name": "Team B",
        "image":"https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/680.png"
    }
    ],
    "location": {
        "@type": "Place",
        "address": "Stadium of Team A"
    }
}
</script>

<?php endif; ?>
```